# Abstract models of parallel computing?

Tags: complexity-theory, automata, parallel-computing

I am looking for literature on abstract models on parallel computing. I am mainly referring to models like Alternating Turing Machine, PRAM or NC-uniform equivalence (Boolean circuits) with some parallelism capability.

I would like to know if there are any recent advances or literature on the subject.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I am not sure that there is a specific theory of PRAM computers (of types EREW, ERCW, CREW or CRCW). But they are intensely used in the development of parallel algorithms, for which the literature is huge.